# Build failed in ASP.NET Boilerplate when connect with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I use the ASP.NET Boilerplate template version 9.x and .NET 8 but when using the "Add-Migration" template I get the error `"doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again."`. At that time, I updated the packages to the latest version and performed `"Add-Migration"` but got the error `"Build Failed"`. When running the command, I adjusted **DefaultProject to EntityFrameworkCore**

I use PostgreSQL edited the **[]DbContextConfigurer** configuration to

```
public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<[]DbContext> builder, string connectionString)
{
     builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
}

public static void Configure(DbContextOptionsBuilder<[]DbContext> builder, DbConnection connection)
{
     builder.UseNpgsql(connection);
}
```

Comment: please provide the errors behind `Build Failed` so we can help

Comment: Help me, what command should I use to display the error? In cmd only the word Build Failed is displayed